# Header Based Authentication in Owasp zap

Tags: docker, security, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, owasp, zap

I am trying to implement Owasp Zap scan. But I am unable to find script for header authentication

How to add header authentication for the key value pair e.g key =api-key value = 123

```
    docker run --rm -v $(Agent.ReleaseDirectory)/docker:/zap/wrk/:rw -t ictu/zap2docker-weekly zap- 
     baseline.py \
      -t https://www.example.com/ProductDetails/v1/details?productId=123456 \
      -I -x governreport.xml \
       -r testreport.html \
      --hook=/zap/auth_hook.py \ 
        -z "auth.loginurl=https://www.example.com/ProductDetails/v1/details?productId=123456" \
```

I am following this article:

- http://www.winkell.co.uk/2019/10/28/zap-security-scanning-in-azure-devops-release-pipelines/

Comment: Not familiar with Azure DevOps but I use the [`owasp/zap2docker-stable`](https://hub.docker.com/r/owasp/zap2docker-stable/) images in my pipelines. The headers being set correctly really depends on what the application requires (i.e. I use [`keycloak`](https://www.keycloak.org/) which expects form based authentication to obtain the token) and how that's handled in the [hook](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/scan-hooks/) (I'm using a custom `zap_started` hook).

Comment: Not get your latest information, is  masseyb's suggestion helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: @WalterQian-MSFT yes I am still struggling to find a solution

Answer (score 2):

To add the header you want you can include the following options in your `-z`

```
  -config replacer.full_list\\(0\\).description=auth1 \  
  -config replacer.full_list\\(0\\).enabled=true \  
  -config replacer.full_list\\(0\\).matchtype=REQ_HEADER \  
  -config replacer.full_list\\(0\\).matchstr=Authorization \  
  -config replacer.full_list\\(0\\).regex=false \  
  -config replacer.full_list\\(0\\).replacement=123456789
```

So your command would look something like

```
    docker run --rm -v $(Agent.ReleaseDirectory)/docker:/zap/wrk/:rw -t ictu/zap2docker-weekly zap- 
 baseline.py \
  -t https://www.example.com/ProductDetails/v1/details?productId=123456 \
  -I -x governreport.xml \
   -r testreport.html \
  --hook=/zap/auth_hook.py \ 
    -z "auth.loginurl=https://www.example.com/ProductDetails/v1/details?productId=123456" \
  -config replacer.full_list\\(0\\).description=auth1 \  
  -config replacer.full_list\\(0\\).enabled=true \  
  -config replacer.full_list\\(0\\).matchtype=REQ_HEADER \  
  -config replacer.full_list\\(0\\).matchstr=api-key \  
  -config replacer.full_list\\(0\\).regex=false \  
  -config replacer.full_list\\(0\\).replacement=123
```

With this you will have the header `api-key: 123` added to all of your requests.

Reference: https://www.zaproxy.org/blog/2017-06-19-scanning-apis-with-zap/

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you just need to set the authentication header is to use the [Authentication Env Vars](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/authentication/handling-auth-yourself/#authentication-env-vars)

**Snippet from the link:**
"If your app just needs one authentication token which you can generate outside of ZAP then you can use the ZAP Authentication environmental variables.

There are 3 of these env vars which are documented on the Desktop User Guide Authentication page and reproduced here for completeness:

- **ZAP_AUTH_HEADER_VALUE** - if this is defined then its value will be added as a header to all of the requests
- **ZAP_AUTH_HEADER** - if this is defined then its value will be used as the header name - if it is not defined then the standard Authorization header will be used
- **ZAP_AUTH_HEADER_SITE** - if this is defined then the header will only be included in sites whose name includes its value.

The env vars are standard operating system env vars so how you will need to set them will depend on your OS and possibly your shell. They need to be set before you start ZAP, they cannot be set once ZAP is already running."